# StandardML 97 definition

Tags: ml

Actual Standard ML specification is [The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)](http://mitpress.mit.edu/0262631814)
, which available on MITPress only in a print version.

Is it availaible in electronic format (pdf, ps, i.e.)?

Answer (score 2):

No.

I see this as a mistake. The specification of a language ought to be free. Otherwise, you limit the amount of people interested in it automatically. To be fair though, the Definition of SML is really good work - and far more encompassing than any other lang. specification. It has probably also taken a lot more time to write!

Comment: The standards for a lot of standardized languages (e.g. C) are also not free.

Comment: While this is a true point, I don't think that any modern language should seek to make the standard something you have to buy. It severely limits the exposition of implementations, and in Standard MLs case, it is one of the reasons it never took off as a language.

Answer (score 0):

The Definition was recently made available by MIT Press and [the source is on Github](https://github.com/SMLDefinition/definition), including instructions on how to compile a PDF.

Comment: that appears to be SML90, not SML97